# Word for banks and other institutions taking possession of your assets because you didn't comply with the contract

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word or expression for this process?

When a family doesn't have enough money and has to move out because their house is now owned by the bank, what's the word for what happened to the house?

> The house was ____ by the bank

Or when you mortgage valuable items to borrow money and you can't pay the debt, what happens to your golden watch or your car, for example?

> My car was ____ by the bank

If these are not the correct sentence structures for the situation, what's the best way to express the idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are [**repossessed**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/repossess).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: For houses, you can also say [foreclosed on](https://www.lexico.com/definition/foreclose).

Comment: If a mortgage is taken out on a property (either to buy the property or to raise money for another purpose) and the customer defaults on the payment the bank will, eventually, _foreclose on_ the property. If someone has a debt which is not related to an asset but the asset is taken under a court order in order for it to be sold to pay off the debt the asset is _seized_. Only assets where a loan is taken out through the seller in order to pay for the asset is the asset _repossessed_.

Comment: @BoldBen thank you for the clarification, it was very helpful.

Comment: In 1970 I knew a revolutionary commune a member of which which bought a big Victorian house in Clifton, Bristol for a ludicrously low sum, £5,000 I think. Nobody wanted them. They had a 10 year mortgage. After 2 years the commune fell apart and they stopped paying the mortgage. The lender foreclosed. In those two years there had been a property boom and after the lender had sold the house at auction and deducting costs they were obliged to hand my friends £20,000. 1970s prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***repossess***

to take back possession of something, especially property that has not been completely paid for:

[-Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/repossess)

The house was re-possesed by the bank... the mortgage was

***foreclosed.***

> (especially of banks) to take back property that was bought with borrowed money because the money was not being paid back as formally agreed:

With vehicles, it is sometimes said

***repo-ed***

From Repo as a business.

Comment: The option you do not have, and which the OP specifically mentioned, is where you put up a valuable asset which you own outright as security for a loan which is not a mortgage. In this case the bank can't _foreclose_ on the asset because the loan us not a mortgage. Also it can't _repossess_ the item since it never possessed it in the first place. The process by which a financial  institution takes possession of an asset so that they can sell it and recover the unpaid money is, in the UK at least, called _seizure_ and the asset is said to be _seized_ by the institution.